# Modules for RTF with inline images + word limits?

Tags: 7, media, forms, nodes

I want to allow all users of my sites to add there own blog post, with certain constraints.

Here's the form I want to give them:

`Title`:

`Contents (RTF, max 700 characters)`:

`Submit (or Login/Register then Submit)`:

Mandatory for all posts to:

- enable read/write permissions on comments
- be published to the /const/ with the title they initially provided
- allow edits and unpublishing by administrators